# FOSUserBundle add field to registration form in event subscriber

Tags: php, forms, symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm trying to dynamically add fields to registration form using FOSUserBundle.

I tried this:

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return array(
      FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE => 'preSetData',
    );
}

public function preSetData(GetResponseUserEvent $event)
{
    $user = $event->getUser();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    switch($user->getType()){
        case 'x':
            $form->add('y');
            break;

    }
}
```

but class which is recieved in preSetData argument(GetResponseUserEvent) doesn't let me to modify form, only user. Is there a way to modify registration form like this?

Can this be done with multiple user forms, extending base form with logic in custom registerAction since it looks like more elegant solution? If so, how could i achieve that?